# How can I move files with one specific extension, with absolute paths / folder structure?

Tags: bash, encryption, sh, backup

I became a victim of the HERMES 2.1 ransomware on October 30.
It encrypted half my disk before I noticed it. My instant reaction was to kill the process and to shut down the computer. Now I booted up Kali Linux to prevent further damage and to ask this question:
The encrypted files are not very imported, so I decided to move the encrypted files to a backup drive and wait until RSA-2048 will be broken or a decrypter will be released. Then I will be able to decrypt them, and move them back or whatever. The encrypted files got the .hrm file extension. I want to ask now: How can I move all encrypted files to another drive, while keeping the folder structure intact, so I can determine the whole damage and move the files back eventually? I'm not that of a Linux guy, and I'm still concerned of booting into Windows.

Also, I have just recently swapped the hard drive, before it got encrypted. Is there any hope of recovering the files on the old hard drive and to replace the encrypted files from the current disk and to replace them with the recovered files? After all, corrupted files are still better than encrypted.

Anyway, I hope my question isn't too off-topic here. Just you have to understand me being frustrated about that encounter.

Comment: Yes, your question is too off-topic. Better post this in Server Fault or Super User

Answer (score 0):

In general, StackOverflow requests that you show some effort that you have put in the question. Also, novice questions with Kali are a bit ignored; Kali is for advanced users, not for beginners.

But what you want is to create a copy of the directory structure and then copy all the .hrm extensions in it. That is easy:

```
find path-of-windows-drive -type d -exec mkdir -p path-of-dest/{} \; -print
find path-of-windows-drive -name '*.hrm' -exec cp {} path-of-dest/{} \; -print
```

If everything is ok, you might delete the .hrm's with

```
find path-of-windows-drive -name '*.hrm' -exec rm -f {}
```

But some additional advice: buy a cheap USB harddrive and do a complete copy (`cp -r`) to that drive. Put a sticker on that copy with "WARNING: INFECTED" + the date, and store that. I predict that you might be needing that copy sometime.